# Не могу разобраться с Grab

Tags: python, grab

Приветствую. Для ознакомления решил распарсить сайт с объявлениями, но возникла проблема в понимании того, как работает парсер.

Пример одного объявления:

```
<div class="obj">
    <a class="title">Продам что-то</a>
    <img src="/blabla.jpg">
    <img src="/blabla2.jpg">
    <div class="description">Описание</div>
</div>
```

Изначально я себе представлял так:
elem является объектом, в котором содержится одно объявление `<div class="obj">...</div>`

Дальше я хотел, используя elem, найти текст в нужных мне элементах, подскажите как это сделать?

Удобно бы было так `elem.rex('<a[^>]+</a>').group(0)`, но увы это не подходит.

```
from grab import Grab

g = Grab()
g.setup(timeout = 15, connect_timeout = 10)
g.go('http://site.dev')

for elem in g.xpath_list('//div[@class="obj"]'):
    print "?"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод xpath_list в данный момент считается устаревшим. 
Используйте вместо него `g.doc.select('//div[@class="obj"]')`, он вернет вам селектор.

```
sel = g.doc.select('//div[@class="obj"]')
divs = sel.node_list()
for elem in divs:
    print "?"
```